# How can i stack pandas dataframes with different column names vertically

Tags: python, pandas

I have 2 dataframes that looks like this:

```
Index1   Games1
   1        1   
   2        5
   3        10
Index2   Games2
   4        2   
   5        4
   6        6
```

How can I combine them to make it like this:

```
Index   Games
   1        1   
   2        5
   3        10
   4        2   
   5        4
   6        6
```

Thank you!

Comment: pd.concat([df1,df2])

Comment: You have one dataframe or two?

Comment: I have 2 dataframes and cocat creates 4 columns instead of 2

Comment: `pd.DataFrame(np.vstack((df1.values,df2.values)))`

Comment: @QuangHoang that works thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy

# Assuming your dataframes are named df1, and df2

new_frame = pd.DataFrame(numpy.vstack((df1.values, df2.values)))

print(new_frame)
```

This method creates a new dataframe by performing the [`vstack`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.vstack.html) operation out of the [`numpy`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/index.html) library.

Vstack is essentially a way of concatenating, but stacks them in sequence, preserving their row order.

Comment: Awesome. Feel free to accept this as an answer so others can use it. I see @QuangHoang beat me to the punch, but posted as a comment, so if that user posts as an answer, please accept theirs instead.

Comment: Yea I tried to accept your answer but there's a time limit. I will wait for a while to see if QuangHoang wants to post then I will accept his.